# Error when compiling the code, linker command failed?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am relatively new to C++ and I am using CLions. I am trying to run this code as follows:

```
/*
 * File: Warmup.cpp
 * ----------------


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "../lib/StanfordCPPLib/console.h"
#include "../lib/StanfordCPPLib/simpio.h"
using namespace std;

/* Constants */

const int HASH_SEED = 5381;               /* Starting point for first cycle */
const int HASH_MULTIPLIER = 33;           /* Multiplier for each cycle      */
const int HASH_MASK = unsigned(-1) >> 1;  /* All 1 bits except the sign     */

/* Function prototypes */

int hashCode(string key);

/* Main program to test the hash function */

int main() {
   string name = getLine("Please enter your name: John");
   int code = hashCode(name);
   cout << "The hash code for your name is " << code << "." << endl;
   return 0;
}

/*
 * Function: hash
 * Usage: int code = hashCode(key);
 * --------------------------------


int hashCode(string str) {
   unsigned hash = HASH_SEED;
   int nchars = str.length();
   for (int i = 0; i < nchars; i++) {
      hash = HASH_MULTIPLIER * hash + str[i];
   }
   return (hash & HASH_MASK);
}
```

However, I am getting the following errors:

> [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Warmup.dir/src/Warmup.cpp.o
>   [100%] Linking CXX executable Warmup ld: library not found for
>   -llib/StanfordCPPLib clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make[3]: *** [Warmup] Error 1
>   make[2]:**  [CMakeFiles/Warmup.dir/all] Error 2 make[1]: 
>   **[CMakeFiles/Warmup.dir/rule] Error 2 make: *** [Warmup] Error 2

I know that this works for microsoft studio C++ but I am not sure why it isnt running for CLions. Would someone mind giving some advice here ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: This is what my current CMakeLists.txt file looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(0_Warmup)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILE src/Warmup.cpp)
link_libraries(lib/StanfordCPPLib)

add_executable(Warmup src/Warmup.cpp)
```

Am I making an error linking this library somewhere ?

Comment: It looks like you are using a library `lib/StanfordCPPLib`and it cannot be found. is it in the appropriate folder?

Comment: How does you linker command line actually look? You can add pathes used to lookup libraries with the `-L<path>` option.

Comment: @Hayt In my CMakeLists.txt file, I have `link_libraries(lib/StanfordCPPLib)` . I also have it in folder stored as lib/StanfordCPPLib where I marked the lib folder as a library root because the compiler does not allow me to import the needed header files when I simply mark StanfordCPPLib as a library root.

Comment: Do you have a file like StanfordCPPLib.a or StanfordCPPLib.so or StanfordCPPLib.lib

Comment: @Hayt Hm, no I don't.. I suppose that means that I did not specify it in the appropriate folder I suppose. Would you mind helping me to explain how I could go about doing so ?

Comment: You need one of those files to link against a library they should be somewhere from where you also got the header files from. putting them in the "lib" folder should solve this.

Comment: @Hayt I tried looking for it but I couldn't find anything those files. Is there anyway to manually link it or through some other methods ? All that is in the files are some .cpp and header files

Comment: Then you should have the cpp files too for the library. This means you have to compile the library yourself and then you can link against it

Comment: @Hayt Actually I managed to get the .lib file and I kept it in the LIb folder, but I still seemed to get the same error for some reason.

Comment: what operating system are you on?

Comment: You also should use something like this: `link_directories(lib)` and `link_libraries(StanfordCPPLib)`

Comment: @Hayt I'm using a Mac, I tried the two `link_directories(lib)` and `link_libraries(StanfordCPPLib)` but  it still tells me that the library is not found.

Comment: When using a mac I assume you compile with gcc or clang? you need a .so or .a file for this.

Comment: @Hayt thanks for the help ! I have been able to work things out and eventually switched over to Visual Studios. Because I was quite a beginner to C++ at the time of writing, I didn't know the many compiler issues that the language faced. Nonetheless, I have figured it out now. Thank you

Answer (score -3):

I think u added above this //

```
#include "../lib/StanfordCPPLib/console.h"
#include "../lib/StanfordCPPLib/simpio.h"// library and u shud try once again a right path of library folder ..
```

Comment: I don't think this solves anything here. The problem seems to be that cmake / the linker cannot find the needed library.